# No puedo obtener valor de radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html

Quisiera obtener el value del radiobutton activo del grupo "tipo_sancion"

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/cambio.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/refrescado.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/borrar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/pasar.js"></script>
</head>

<form action="procesar.php" method="post">

<body onload="refrescado();">


<label for="name"> nombre </label>  <br/>
<input type="text" name="nombre" onclick="pasar()" placeholder="ingrese su nombre">
 <br/>

<label for="codigo"> codigo </label>  <br/>
<input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="ingrese el codigo">
<br/>

                <input type="radio" id="tipo_sacion1" name="tipo_sancion" onclick="toggle(this);borrar()" value="0" checked> Ninguno<br>
                <input type="radio" id="tipo_sacion2" name="tipo_sancion" onclick="toggle(this);borrar()" value="1" > Agravante <br>
                <input type="radio" id="tipo_sacion3" name="tipo_sancion" onclick="toggle(this);borrar()" value="2"> Atenuante <br>


<div id="uno">
Elija su comida fuerte

<?php
echo "</br>";
$registros= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM comida_fuerte");
while($comida = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='comida_fuerte[]' value='".$comida["id_comida_fuerte"]."'>".$comida["desc_comida_fuerte"]."</br>";
}
?>
<br/>
</div>

<div id="dos">

Elija su sopa
<?php
echo "</br>";
$registros2= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM comida_sopa");
while($comida2 = mysqli_fetch_array($registros2)){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='comida_sopa[]' value='".$comida2["id_comida_sopa"]."'>".$comida2["desc_comida_sopa"]."</br>";
}
?>
<br/>
</div>

<input type="submit"  value="registrar"*>
</form>

</html>
```

Procesar.php:

```
   <?php
include 'conexion.php';

$nombre = $_REQUEST["nombre"]; 
echo "nombre".var_dump($nombre);

$codigo = $_REQUEST["codigo"];
echo "codigo".var_dump($codigo);

$tipo_sancion=$_REQUEST["tipo_sacion"];
echo "tipo_sacion".var_dump($tipo_sancion);







/*if($tipo_sancion>0){
    if($tipo_sancion==1) {
        $comida_fuerte=$_REQUEST["comida_fuerte"];
echo "comida_fuerte".var_dump($comida_fuerte);
    }elseif($tipo_sacion==2){

$comida_sopa=$_REQUEST["comida_sopa"];
echo "comida_sopa".var_dump($comida_sopa);
}else{

}


foreach ($comida_fuerte as $co_fu):
$insertar = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT into comprador_comida (id_comida_fuerte,id_comprador) values ('$comida_fuerte','$codigo')");
endforeach;
unset($co_fu);

foreach ($comida_sopa as &$co_so):
$insertar2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT into comprador_comida ('id_comida_sopa','id_comprador') values ('$comida_sopa','$codigo')");
endforeach;
unset($co_so);*/
?>
```

ERROR QUE PRESENTA:

> Notice: Undefined index: tipo_sacion in C:\procesar.php on line 10

Valor devuelto:

> NULL tipo_sacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es en  `tipo_sacion`

corrigelo por `tipo_sancion`

Comment: X-rw, esto es más un comentario que respuesta. La pregunta no es reproducible debido a un error tipografico.

Comment: @lois6b no puedo eliminar mi respuesta

Comment: porque ha recibido votos. ...